# GridsearchCV and RFECV with python

Tags: python, pipeline, grid-search, rfe

I am training a model and for that I need an attribute selector (with RFECV) and then I need to optimize the parameters of the model (GridSearchCV).

**Code**

```
model = LogisticRegression() #algorithm

my_scorer = make_scorer(score, greater_is_better=True) #The score

generador_train = GroupKFold(n_splits=10).split(X_train, y_train, order_train) #Generator 10 splits with order
C= {'C': 10. ** np.arange(-3, 4)} #C
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler() #Standardized
selector =RFECV(cv=generador_train, estimator=model,scoring=my_scorer) #Selection of attributes

pipe=Pipeline([('scaler', scaler),('select', selector),('model', model)]) # The pipeline is created


grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=C,cv=generador_train,scoring=my_scorer,refit=True) #The gridSearch with CV is declared

grid.fit(X_train, y_train) # The pipeline is executed        
best_pipe=grid.best_estimator_
```

When executing the previous code I get the error:

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-34-9d038a773283> in <module>()
>      17 
>      18     grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=C,cv=generador_train,scoring=my_scorer,refit=True) #Se
> declara el gridSearch con CV
> ---> 19     grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
>      20     best_pipe=grid.best_estimator_
>
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py
> in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
>     622                                      n_candidates * n_splits))
>     623 
> --> 624         base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
>     625         pre_dispatch = self.pre_dispatch
>     626 
>
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      59     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
>      60     for name, param in six.iteritems(new_object_params):
> ---> 61         new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
>      62     new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
>      63     params_set = new_object.get_params(deep=False)
>
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      47     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
>      48     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
> ---> 49         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
>
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in <listcomp>(.0)
>      47     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
>      48     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
> ---> 49         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
>
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      47     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
>      48     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
> ---> 49         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
>
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in <listcomp>(.0)
>      47     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
>      48     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
> ---> 49         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
>
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      59     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
>      60     for name, param in six.iteritems(new_object_params):
> ---> 61         new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
>      62     new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
>      63     params_set = new_object.get_params(deep=False)
>
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
> ---> 52             return copy.deepcopy(estimator)
>      53         else:
>      54             raise TypeError("Cannot clone object '%s' (type %s): "
>
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\copy.py in
> deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
>     167                     reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce_ex__", None)
>     168                     if reductor:
> --> 169                         rv = reductor(4)
>     170                     else:
>     171                         reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce__", None)
>
> TypeError: can't pickle generator objects
> ```

How can it be solved? Which may be due?

**UPDATE 1**

I have put:

```
list(generador_train = GroupKFold(n_splits=10).split(X_train, y_train, order_train))
```

but I have obtained this error:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-150-d0ca294b7811> in <module>()
>  25 
>  26 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=C, cv=generador_train,scoring=my_scorer,refit=True) #Se declara el gridSearch con  CV
> ---> 27 grid.fit(X_train, y_train) # Se ejecuta la pipeline
>  28 #grid.fit(digits.data, digits.target)
>  29 #res=pipe.named_steps['select'].grid_scores_ #Resultados gridSearch
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
> 637                                   error_score=self.error_score)
> 638           for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params,
> --> 639                                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
> 640 
> 641         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train score info
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in     __call__(self, iterable)
> 777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
> 778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
> --> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
> 780                 self._iterating = True
> 781             else:
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in  dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
> 623                 return False
> 624             else:
> --> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
> 626                 return True
> 627 
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
> 586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
> 587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
> --> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
> 589         self._jobs.append(job)
> 590 
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
> 109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
> 110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
> --> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
> 112         if callback:
> 113             callback(result)
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
> 330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
> 331         # arguments in memory
> --> 332         self.results = batch()
> 333 
> 334     def get(self):
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
> 129 
> 130     def __call__(self):
> --> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
> 132 
> 133     def __len__(self):
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
> 129 
> 130     def __call__(self):
> --> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
> 132 
> 133     def __len__(self):
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
> 456             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
> 457         else:
> --> 458             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
> 459 
> 460     except Exception as e:
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
> 246             This estimator
> 247         """
> --> 248         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
> 249         if self._final_estimator is not None:
> 250             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
> 211                 Xt, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
> 212                     cloned_transformer, None, Xt, y,
> --> 213                     **fit_params_steps[name])
> 214                 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
> 215                 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 360 
> 361     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
> --> 362         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
> 363 
> 364     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, weight, X, y, **fit_params)
> 579                        **fit_params):
> 580     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
> --> 581         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
> 582     else:
> 583         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
> 518         else:
> 519             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
> --> 520             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
> 521 
> 522 
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py in fit(self, X, y)
> 434         scores = parallel(
> 435             func(rfe, self.estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
> --> 436             for train, test in cv.split(X, y))
> 437 
> 438         scores = np.sum(scores, axis=0)
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py in <genexpr>(.0)
> 434         scores = parallel(
> 435             func(rfe, self.estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
> --> 436             for train, test in cv.split(X, y))
> 437 
> 438         scores = np.sum(scores, axis=0)
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py in _rfe_single_fit(rfe, estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
>  26     Return the score for a fit across one fold.
>  27     """
>  ---> 28     X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train)
>  29     X_test, y_test = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, test, train)
>  30     return rfe._fit(
>
>  ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in _safe_split(estimator, X, y, indices, train_indices)
> 198             X_subset = X[np.ix_(indices, train_indices)]
> 199     else:
> --> 200         X_subset = safe_indexing(X, indices)
> 201 
> 202     if y is not None:
>
> ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in safe_indexing(X, indices)
> 158                                    indices.dtype.kind == 'i'):
> 159             # This is often substantially faster than X[indices]
> --> 160             return X.take(indices, axis=0)
> 161         else:
> 162             return X[indices]
>
> IndexError: index 182 is out of bounds for size 182
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

There are 2 ítems with the same id that can't be separated when I Split the data.

Order_train creation:

```
order = mydata.iloc[:,0].values #Ids that are used by the order.  
train_indices, test_indices = next(GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=0.25).split(X, y, order)) #Split the data into train and test using groups.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train_indices], X[test_indices], y[train_indices], y[test_indices] #Obtain the 4 datasets
order_train=mydata.iloc[train_indices,0].values #Order train
```

Order_train:

```
[  1.   1.   2.   2.   3.   3.   4.   4.   5.   5.   6.   6.
7.   7.   8.   8.   9.   9.   10.   10.   11.   11.   12.   12.
13.   13.   14.   14.   15.   15.   16.   16.   17.   17.   18.   18.
19.   19.   20.   20.   21.   21.   22.   22.   23.   23.   24.   24.
25.   25.   26.   26.   27.   27.   28.   28.   29.   29.   30.   30.
31.   31.   32.   32.   33.   33.   34.   34.   35.   35.   36.   36.
37.   37.   38.   38.   39.   39.   40.   40.   41.   41.   42.   42.
43.   43.   44.   44.   45.   45.   46.   46.   47.   47.   48.   48.
49.   49.   50.   50.   51.   51.   52.   52.  53.  53.  54.  54.
55.  55.  56.  56.  57.  57.  58.  58.  59.  59.  60.  60.
61.  61.  62.  62.  63.  63.  64.  64.  65.  65.  66.  66.
67.  67.  68.  68.  69.  69.  70.  70.  71.  71.  72.  72.
73.  73.  74.  74.  75.  75.  76.  76.  77.  77.  78.  78.
79.  79.  80.  80.  81.  81.  82.  82.  83.  83.  84.  84.
85.  85.  86.  86.  87.  87.  88.  88.  89.  89.  90.  90.
91.  91.  92.  92.  93.  93.  94.  94.  95.  95.  96.  96.
97.  97.  98.  98.  99.  99.  100.  100.  101.  101.  102.  102.]
```

Comment: Just do `generador_train = GroupKFold(n_splits=10)`. Scikit-learn will internally automatically do the splits.

Comment: Yes, but I need that GroupKFold makes the splits using an order.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `"I need that GroupKFold makes the splits using an order."` I assume that you are talking about passing `groups = order_train` into the GroupKFold. You can pass that to the `GridSearchCV.fit()`. It will be automatically passed to the GroupKFold to get the splits in the order you want.

Currently you are attempting to do:

```
generador_train = GroupKFold(n_splits=10).split(X_train, y_train, order_train) 

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, 
                   param_grid=C,
                   cv=generador_train,
                   scoring=my_scorer,
                   refit=True) 

grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

What I am implying is that you can do this:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, 
                   param_grid=C,
                   cv=GroupKFold(n_splits=10),
                   scoring=my_scorer,
                   refit=True) 

grid.fit(X_train, y_train, order_train)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I added the order_train in grid.fit() I obtain this error: "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [204, 204, 1]"

Comment: @adamista When you used `order_train` in `GroupKFold.split()` I assume `order_train` is passed for the `groups` param. From this error I think thats not the case. Can you tell what is `order_train` and show its content?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have added the order_train creation in my question. If I put: "grid.fit(X_train,y_train,groups=order_train)" the error is: "The 'groups' parameter should not be None."